# Multiple Wordpress Installations on a Single Domain name

Tags: xampp, filezilla

I want to set up Multiple Wordpress Installations on a Single Domain name. I need a wordpress installation for my webdeveloper website, and other installations for developing customer websites. After development I would have to move these new websites to client server. Technical staff of my web hosting company suggested two possibilities:
1)development.domainame.com     (create a subdomain for additional wordpress installation)
2)domainame.com/development     (use subfolder for additional wordpress installation

They recommended to use solution 1). May I know the pro and con of each solution ? And would be a best practise ? Thx in advance

PS: I cant use multisite, not suited for my case

Answer (score 0):

Your web host's technical staff is correct. You have 2 options:

- Use Subdomains. ex: sub1.mydomain.com vs sub2.mydomain.com
- Use Subfolders. ex: mydomain.com/folder1 vs mydomain.com/folder2

The benefit of using subdomains is that the "environments" are separated. The two websites will act like they are entirely different websites, making it easier to migrate the clients site in the future.

The benefit of using subfolders is that it's easier to "switch in between the sites". You could access all the files using the same FTP login.

I would suggest the use of subdomains. It separates the sites into 2 clearly different sites, will make it easier to restrict client/user access by-subdomain, and will decrease the chances that making a change to one site would affect the other (for example, if you have 2 wordpress sites as subfolders, it would be much easier to accidentally edit or change the wrong mysql database table)